# Python GUI with Multithreading - how to manage threads

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I am new to Python. I have been trying to develop a GUI based tool to monitor a set of databases. I want to pull data with multiple threads to make the DB reads faster. I found that threads can be managed using `threading` class or `concurrent.futures` class or using `queue`. In my tool there will be frequent DB reads and GUI will updated accordingly. My question is - what will be best option to work with for threading ? And how to manage life cycle of threads ?

I tried few example provided in different websites with following results.

1. threads created using `threading` class are nicely updating the GUI. But I don't know how to manage 30 threads.
2. Threads created using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` are managed by the class. But it is updating the GUI after all the threads complete their task.

Answer (score 1):

The thing with python threading is that there isn't really a proper way to stop a thread without stopping the entire execution. I am guessing your using `threading` or `_thread`

What I would do is create a list and have each function access a certain index of the list.
Process ID = Item in list.
thread 0 would be checking item 0 in list "running".
an example using `_thread`

```py
import _thread
running = []
def task(id):
  global running
  while running[id]:
    #do something
#Create 5 tasks
for i in range(0,6):
  running.append(True)
  _thread.start_new_thread(task,(i,))
# Now lets stop tasks 2 and 4.
running[1] = False
running[3] = False
# After doing this the threads will end once code in while loop has finished
# To restart tasks 2 and 4
_thread.start_new_thread(task,(1,))
_thread.start_new_thread(task,(3,))
```

This is my rudimentary way of managing tasks.
It may or may not work for you.
I am not a professional. But it works.